# RewriteRule with proxying?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I'm setting up a RewriteRule, but at the moment it just redirects the browser. What I want is proxying, so that the user does not recognise the url changed behind.

I came around the P flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ... [P]
```

which is the same as a `ProxyPass` statement.

Now: how do I make a `ReverseProxyPass` statement within my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, but you can often make it work the way you need it anyway.

First off, make sure you need to use `RewriteRule` instead of simply `ProxyPass`.  The rule you've provided is quite simple; if you don't have some `RewriteCond` logic in front if it, then you can just as easily use `ProxyPass`.

In any case, let's take an example where you're doing something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/proxied-location/(.*)$ http://backend/$1 [P]
```

So, you're taking a request for `http://your-apache-server/proxied-location/something.html` and sending it to the backend without the `/proxied-location/` part of the URL.

A redirecting (`30x`) response would not include the `/proxied-location/` part of the URL, despite the fact that the client needs that in order to access the other resource through the proxy.  That's what `ProxyPassReverse` handles.  So, just add a configuration like this:

```
ProxyPassReverse /proxied-location/ http://backend/
```

The config only applies on requests where the proxy backend handles the response, so the "conditions" that you've applied with `mod_rewrite` effectively still apply.

Make sense?

Comment: Ok cool thanks for your explain. But I still struggle how to use this. Eg: I have a condition, based on this cond I want every request to be mapped to an entirely new address. Regardless of what the requested url is. eg `RewriteRule ^/whatever/ http://myhomeserver:8080/manager`. This would forward any request to my apache manager console. How should I now write the `ProxyPassReverse` statement, as the destination url does not have anything in common with the request (anyhow the requested url should still be visible to the user)?

Comment: @membersound Well, I'd recommend against that, since the manager webapp uses resources other than just `/manager`; pages the user would visit are `/manager/status` or `/manager/html/list`, and it loads resources like `/manager/images/asf-logo.gif`.  But in a theoretical situation where you'd only want to allow access to a single, specific resource, that'll still work fine: `ProxyPassReverse /whatever http://myhomeserver:8080/manager`

Comment: the manager console is just an example for testing as i do not have a webapp yet. of course 8 will not expose it to the user. thx